# which is the meaning and in which occasions you use the expression: "out and about"?

Tags: meaning

My colleague used "out and about" in a work environment and I'm not sure what she was meaning.
Could you help me.
Thank you.
Lorenzo

Comment: Just going for a wander or going outside generally

Comment: The exact meaning depends on context, but basically if you say you were *out and about* yesterday, it means you spent a lot of time (probably in more than one place, probably doing different things) yesterday somehwere other than where you would normally have been (the office, or your home, for example). You were *out* of your normal location, going *about* your business (doing whatever it is you do/did). It's a pretty informal usage, I'd say - often used *specifically* in order to be vague about exactly *what* you were doing.

Comment: @FF I've always regarded it as an example of a 'Siamese Twin' redundancy. [The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/out-and-about) doesn't mention the 'about one's normal business' sense of 'about': 'Well enough to come and go, especially after an illness. For example, I'm glad to see you're out and about again. [Late 1800s ]'.

Comment: It means what it says.  "Out" means "outside", and "about" means moving around -- not in one specific location.  (Of course, "outside" may simply mean, eg, "outside my office", while still inside the larger office building or some such.)

Comment: In my experience (in the UK) it means out (of bed) and about (daily business). It can be after an illness, or simply in the morning: "Is Fred still sleeping, or is he out and about yet?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a 'general reference' question; *i.e.* it can be answered simply by looking it up in a dictionary:

> **out and about** ([Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/out-and-about?q=out+and+about))
>
> Engaging in normal activity after an illness. *(British English definition)*
>   (Of a person, especially after inactivity) engaging in normal activity. *(American English definition)*
>
> Same examples from both British & American English definitions:
>   *Again, this was all due to my illness and generally not getting **out and about**.*
>   *Many of the activities for the next seven days focus on getting **out and about** in the Ilkley area.*
>   *Maria is currently a bit under the weather and all her friends and family hope to see her **out and about** again real soon.*

---

> **out and about** ([Cambridge Dictionary - British English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-and-about)) *(No American English definition)*
>
> active; doing the things you usually do:
>   *The doctor says she's making a good recovery, and she should be **out and about** in a few days' time.*

---

> **out and about** ([Collins English Dictionary - Retrieved from Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/out-and-about))
>
> regularly going out of the house to work, take part in social activity, etc, esp after an illness

---

> **out and about** ([The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Retrieved from Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/out-and-about))
>
> Well enough to come and go, especially after an illness. [Late 1800s]
>   *I'm glad to see you're out and about again.*

---

The alternative expressions **up and about**, **up and around**, and **up and doing** can also be used with similar meanings:

> **up and around** ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/up--and--about))
>   recovered from an illness; able to leave one's bed.

---

> **up and about** ([The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Retrieved from Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/up--and--about))
>
> Also, **up and around**; **up and doing**.
>
> Active again, especially after an illness or rest. [Early 1800s]
>   *They had her up and about just one day after surgery*
>   *I'm so glad you're up and around; we need your help*
>   *It's time to be up and doing.*

Comment: In my experience here in the US, "up and around" is used for someone recovering from illness, but "out and about" does not carry that connotation (though it may be used to describe such a person).

Comment: @HotLicks I did wonder that from your earlier comment, and from the AmE definition I quoted at the top.

Comment: You share a cube with Fred, who is usually found grinding away at his desk.  But when someone comes in and asks where he's gone, you know he's out seeking a birthday present for his wife.  So you reply "He's out and about", meaning he's not on the premises and not apt to return soon.  If he had just stepped out to use the facilities or to chat with a coworker it would be "He's around here somewhere."

Answer (score 1):

The idiom has a meaning like
- taking a walk outside.
Not confined to the house and active,normal.
We may say "He is fine now,he is out and about."
"You may get wet if you're out and about and do not carry the umbrella"
Hope it helps.

Comment: It is key to note that "out and about" usually carries with it the implication that the subject has recovered from something that has prevented him/her from going about a normal routine, such as illness.  It's not just "taking a walk"; the idea is that the person is doing normal stuff like running errands, socializing, and other things that one does out of the house or the bed.

Comment: Yes. i'm  well aware of it and  i have said about illness in my reply,it is a walk of a person who was earlier  rather unwell or sick.